# Smart-Git: Adding new remote svn branch to existing repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, smartgit

I'm trying to add a new remote branch which is in a non standard format and having problems doing so.

I thought maybe just modifying svnkit config file would do it and fetching would do but I'm not getting any results.

Repository Layout is

```
     branches/** 
     master/ 
     release/ 
     prerelease/ <-- this branch is new
```

And here is my configuration file:

```
    [svn-git-remote "svn"] 
        url = http://mysvn:8080/svn/Repo
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/master 
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/* 
        additional-branches = "release:refs/remotes/svn/release;prerelease:refs/remotes/svn/prerelease" 
    [core] 
        processExternals = true 
        processIgnores = true 
        processEols = false 
        processTags = true 
        processOtherProperties = true 
        gitSvnAttributesThreshold = 32
```

Anyone have any guesses as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the `svngitkit.config` file once you have cloned, but you can do that for a fresh clone[[1](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/howtos/6/show?page=config.svn-clone-custom-branch-layout)].

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might only be done, with latest SmartGit versions, by modifying `svngitkit.properties` file, as explained here : https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/SVN%3A+cloning+with+a+custom+branch+layout